# Android UI difficulties

Tags: android, android-layout, android-scrollview, android-layout-weight

My layout was perfect until I decided to add a scrollview.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout android:id="@+id/tableLayout1" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <ScrollView android:id="@+id/scrollView1" android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_weight="1" >
        <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button android:layout_width="match_parent" android:id="@+id/button1" android:text="Start" android:layout_height="50dip" android:onClick="getOutput"></Button>
</TableLayout>
```

I would like the button to stay at the bottom of the screen, I would actually like the scrollview to take up the entire screen. With just the inner table layout it works fine. In the Graphical Layout preview it looks how I want it, but not when I run it.

I would like the scrollview to take up the whole screen except the button, which I'd like to be at the bottom.

Comment: Why are you using TableLayout for this?  When you say you want the button to stay at the bottom of the screen, how is that possible of the scrollview is taking up the entire screen?  Perhaps you can describe more clearly what you want -- as well as what it is you are seeing now.

Comment: I'm not sure why you want a scroll view inside a table layout - it's more common to have the table layout inside the scroll view.

Comment: I tried that, wouldn't work for some reason, thats why I went to tablelayout to try that, which became closest to what I wanted, trying LinearLayout and RelativeLayout now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <ScrollView  android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="0dip" 
        android:layout_weight="1.0">
        <LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical" 
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"> 
            <TableLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
                android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"/> 
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <Button android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="Bottom Button"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tried this before, and again and it makes my app force close

Comment: I did not however try (or see before) the layout_height at 0dip though, thank you!

Comment: Ya thats used to take account of the layout_weight attribute

Comment: I should know this I guess, but how would I get the stack trace anyway?

Comment: WEll you said that your app force closes. In that case you get a list of error messages in the logcat in eclipse. It gives you an idea of what caused the error.

Comment: Oh, was not testing in emulator.. My screen resolution is too small, cant see the bottom half of the screen, so I use my phone to test :/

Answer (score 1):

you could use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout as Root view. Giving Button more weight. That way ScrollView won't take up the whole thing.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting ScrollView fillViewport attribute to true.